# Data Truncated: Cant scroll to Capture all Data Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have got the first 50 dataset from the table but can seem to get all:

```
url='https://definitivehc.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1044bb19da8d4dbfb6a96eb1b4ebf629&view=list&showFilters=false#data'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\scrape\chromedriver")
browser.get(url)

time.sleep(25)

rows_in_table = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="dgrid-row-table"]//tr[td]')
for element in rows_in_table:
    print(element.text.replace('\n', '||'))
```

result:Snippet of first 50 data points

```
Atmore Community Hospital||Short Term Acute Care Hospital||Atmore||AL||36502||Escambia||Alabama||01||053||01053||51||49||6||6||0.00||0.36||2||2.00||46
Gadsden Regional Medical Center||Short Term Acute Care Hospital||Gadsden||AL||35903||Etowah||Alabama||01||055||01055||346||222||40||40||0.00||0.73||124||8.00||47
Riverview Regional Medical Center||Short Term Acute Care Hospital||Gadsden||AL||35901||Etowah||Alabama||01||055||01055||281||256||45||45||0.00||0.26||25||6.00||48
Fayette Medical Center (FKA Weimer Medical Center)||Short Term Acute Care Hospital||Fayette||AL||35555||Fayette||Alabama||01||057||01057||61||45||8||8||0.00||0.23||16||2.00||49
Russellville Hospital||Short Term Acute Care Hospital||Russellville||AL||35653||Franklin||Alabama||01||059||01059||100||49||7||7||0.00||0.40||51||2.00||50
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are dealing with `pbf` content which is fetched from the following [xhr request](https://services7.arcgis.com/LXCny1HyhQCUSueu/arcgis/rest/services/Definitive_Healthcare_USA_Hospital_Beds/FeatureServer/0/query?f=pbf&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=%2A&orderByFields=OBJECTID+ASC&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=50&cacheHint=true&quantizationParameters=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22edit%22%7D). you've to call it and then use a parser such as `osm` to read `OpenStreetMap`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62435422/10035985